# in MVC using JavaScript first create pdf convert of invoice and save in google drive to save?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to create an invoice save in google drive on the invoice page.  But I have only done pdf covert and save only the current location on a file. And can possible with JavaScript , jQuery at time multiple recorded list to divide in pagination
is it possible?